# How to do unit conversion on a Terrain dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, terrain, units

I was wondering if there is a way to change the elevation units of a Terrain dataset (from example from meter to feet)?

Comment: Not that I know of. In tools like Contour_3d you can set the Z factor (multiple) to convert metres to feet or feet to metres. A terrain takes on the spatial reference of the dataset that it resides in, so if the Z units of the dataset are metres (default) then the terrain will be in metres, if it's feet then the terrain units will be in feet.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would apply, but instead of changing the values, could you just change the display.

See if this will help you...check Ryan K's answer.
[Setting default units for Shape_Area to be Acres using ArcGIS Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99542/setting-default-units-for-shape-area-to-be-acres-using-arcgis-desktop-10-0)

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I think that does not work for me. I am trying to intersect the topo with some water surface elevation TINs (created from water surface elevation values on riverine cross sections) that are in feet. I could change the water surface elevation values on the cross sections to meter as a workaround though.