# Renaming ESRI default SHAPE_Length and SHAPE_Area fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, field-mapping

I have been working on a draft feature class that will eventually go into our production database, and I just tested it against my organization's standards, but it fails because the "SHAPE_Length" and "SHAPE_Area" fields that ESRI automatically generates were too long, had underscores, and were not all capitalized. These are requirements that my organization imposed on all field names.

Is it possible to change the name of these fields (not just the *alias*) to something like SHAPE.LEN and SHAPE.AREA?

So far, I tried running feature class to feature class and changing the name in field mappings, but that didn't work. I am using ArcMap 10.4

Comment: I don't think so. Those fields are system generated by the Geodatabase. Do you have other feature classes that don't have the SHAPE_Length fields in your company's system?

Comment: I think you **can** specify the separator in those field names in some obscure setting somewhere in ArcGIS, so you could change the underscore to a period. But I can't remember where that setting is. I'm pretty sure I read it in a comment on a question on this site. I'll see if I can find it. IIRC it wouldn't allow you to change the name of an existing field, it's something that needs to be specified before you create the geodatabase.

Comment: Both of you seem to be right about the fact that it's native to the geodatabase and not the feature class. I talked with an Admin at my org and he told me that the fields will essentially get reformatted once it goes into the production database. @DanC I'm still interested in whether that's a setting I could change for my project fgdb, so please let me know if you find that question.

Comment: Here's the question that produced the comment I was thinking of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99542/setting-default-units-for-shape-area-to-be-acres-using-arcgis-desktop/99543#99543. It doesn't say how to go about changing that character from `_` to `.` though. It does say that it's a geodatabase configuration issue.

Comment: What type of geodatabase are you trying to do this in?